# How to match Firefox's about page in extension manifest?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to match Firefox's about page like so:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["about:debugging"],
    "js": ["import.js"]
  }
]
```

The script doesn't run. If I try other `matches` it works properly on "normal" websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft, Opera, and Vivaldi these are the things you aren't allowed to modify because they go against extension policies. Meaning, You can't do this, sorry.

**about-scheme**

chrome-extension-scheme

chrome-scheme

edge-extension-scheme

edge-scheme

**moz-extension-scheme**

ms-browser-extension-scheme

opera-scheme

vivaldi-scheme

wyciwyg-scheme

***(In bold are the ones that will effect Firefox)***